# CSS Scrolling Background Image

Tags: css, scroll, background-image

I have an Background Image that i want it to scroll in my canvas.

I am using this code that is not working.

A little help will be strongly appreciated, thank you.

```
    <style>   
        #gameCanvas{background:url("file:///C:/Users/Saqib/Desktop/Game/img/level%20.jpg")}

    body #gameCanvas{ 
    background-image: url('file:///C:/Users/Saqib/Desktop/Game/img/level%201.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not working because the file path you specify in the background-imageL url() is not valid.
You can not use paths from your file system for url, becuase the users who will view this picture in their browsers don't have the same file system as yours. You should link the image with relative path from the file that you are linking it to. For example if the imase is in the same folder with this css file you can write background-image: url("image.jpg")